# Too many outputs

Tags: c

so i've written some example code and was wondering why i get a multiple of the same outputs
when i printf my result after having unwanted inputs.

does anybody has an idea?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int eingabe, ergebnis;

int quer(int result)
{
  result = eingabe*eingabe;
  return result;
}

int check(void)
{
  if (eingabe > 10000)
  {
    printf("\nDie eingegebene Zahl ist zu groß!\n\n");
    main();
  }
  else if (eingabe < 0)
  {
    printf("\nDie eingegebene Zahl ist zu klein!\n\n");
    main();
  }
}

int main()
{
  printf("Bitte geben Sie eine Zahl von 0-10000 ein: ");
  scanf("%d", &eingabe);
  check();
  ergebnis = quer(eingabe);
  printf("%d² = %d\n", eingabe, ergebnis);
}
```

an output example would look like this:

```
Bitte geben Sie eine Zahl von 0-10000 ein: -3

Die eingegebene Zahl ist zu klein!

Bitte geben Sie eine Zahl von 0-10000 ein: 11111

Die eingegebene Zahl ist zu groß!

Bitte geben Sie eine Zahl von 0-10000 ein: 3
3² = 9
3² = 9
3² = 9
```

Comment: Recursively calling `main` is probably not a good idea in this case

Comment: Also your `check` function invokes *undefined behavior* since you declared it to return an `int`, but it doesn't `return` anything

Comment: You should not call main from check, you should return to main from check.

Answer (score 0):

Recursively calling `main` is not a good idea (it’s forbidden by the standard IIRC). In your case, however, it seems to work like a normal function: when you call it yourself, its end does *not* end the program, but returns control instead. So when `main` calls `check` that calls `main`, that inner instance returns, `check` returns  and the `printf` is executed again.

Comment: It's not forbidden to call `main();` in C (it is forbidden in C++), but I agree that it is rarely a good idea

Comment: Oh, thanks for clarifying. Yet another thing against “C++ is extended C.”

Answer (score 0):

Since you have called main in your check function, it justs keeps on going back and forth endlessly. It is never advisable to call main function

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for all your help and suggestions!
i've tried to rewrite some of my code to implement them.
alltough i have one last question how id be possible to ask for input again after the check failed..

```
#include <stdio.h>

int eingabe, ergebnis;
int quer(int result)
{
  result = eingabe*eingabe;
  return result;
}

int check(void)
{
  if (eingabe > 10000)
  {
    printf("mache falsch\n");
    return 0;
  } else if (eingabe < 0)
  {
    printf("mache falsch\n");
    return 0;
  } else
  {
    printf("mache richtig\n");
    return 1;
  }
}

int main()
{
  int checked;
  printf("Bitte geben Sie eine Zahl von 0-10000 ein: ");
  scanf("%d", &eingabe);
  checked = check();
  if (checked == 1) {
    ergebnis = quer(eingabe);
    printf("%d² = %d\n", eingabe, ergebnis);
  } else if (checked == 0){
      printf("Zahl nicht im Wertebereich!\n");
      return 0;
  }
}
```

Comment: Don't use goto.   Use a `while` loop.